# Cant get categories on a loop of products from orders

Tags: magento-1.9

im trying to gett all products and also show the categories of each products from complete orders, but is giving me a strange error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on boolean in /home/site/public_html/csv/getAllOrders.php on line 28

Everything looks ok, i have no idea what is wrong, i already tried to get the categories by loading product id, or sku, but same error, cant figure out what is wrong.
Here is my code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

    foreach ($orders as  $order) {

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

            echo $item->getName() ." - ";
            echo $item->getSku();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$item->getSku());

            if($product->getId()){
                echo implode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>*********************<br>";


    }
```

Comment: can you get your answer???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`$id = $item->getProductId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);`

Comment: I found the problem, but cant find the solution, there are products that  cant get the categoriesID, and this is because the products were deleted and also the categories dont exist, since at the time i think i deleted them and created.So i tried to find some kint of solution in the future to detect type of products in my order, since i cant recover this information of the categories, so i tried to get from the order items the attribute set of the product, but i think even this information is not save on the orders items table. So can someone tell me if there is some kind of solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try below code it is working for me

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

    foreach ($orders as  $order) {

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

            echo $item->getProductId() ." - ";
            echo $item->getSku();

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

            if($product->getId()){
                echo implode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>*********************<br>";


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
if($orders->getSize()) {
  foreach ($orders as  $order) {
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        echo $item->getName() ." - ";
        echo $item->getSku();
        $product = $item->getProduct();

        if($product->getId()){
                echo implode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
        }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>*********************<br>";


  }
}
```